# cURL Adapter uses in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, adapter

I have a project written in plain php by using curl and it’s worked. Now I want to move this project to zend framework 1 (and I am new to zend). I have tried to connect by Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl and I did not get enough information what I need
        My plain php code:
        function server_com($data, $api_host) {

```
       $xml = "xml=".($data); 
       $host = $api_host; 
       //curl initialization
       $cpt = curl_init(); 
       //curl url
       curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$host"); 
       curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); 
       //Return the response as a string instead of outputting it to the screen
       curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
       curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
       // set this true if you want to send a POST request
       curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       //Array of data to POST in request
       curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $data)); 
       //curl execution  
       $result = curl_exec($cpt);

        RETURN $result; 
    }
    $data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Request version="1.0">
            <Export mode="UPDATE" type="COREDATA">
                <Login>
                    <User>user</User>
                    <Password>password</Password>
                </Login>
            </Export>
        </Request>
    ';
    // specifies the URL for the request
    $api_host = "demo.api.net/api/";
    $result = server_com($data, $api_host);
    $fh = fopen("va.xml", "w");
    fwrite($fh,$result);
    fclose($fh);
```

here i am creating va.xml file after query resquest. now, I want this equivalent to Zend framework 1 by using cURL adapter, Can someone please help? I have tried to use zend http client (with cURL adapter) in zend project to replace the cULR part of old php project. I got stuck-up last 2 days. I would really appreciate help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a rough mockup which I've not run; but try it out:

```
$api = "demo.api.net/api/";
$config = array(
    'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
    'curloptions' => array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
    ),
);    

$client = new Zend_Http_Client($api, $config);

$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Request version="1.0">
        <Export mode="UPDATE" type="COREDATA">
            <Login>
                <User>user</User>
                <Password>password</Password>
            </Login>
        </Export>
    </Request>
';

$client->setConfig(array(
    'maxredirects' => 0,
    'timeout'      => 30)
);
$client->setRawData($data, 'text/xml')->request('POST');

$fh = fopen("va.xml", "w");
fwrite($fh,$client->getLastResponse());
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Hello Matt, I am getting the output given below: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2013 10:36:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-powered-by: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-encoding: gzip
Content-length: 5760
Connection: close
Content-type: text/xml

@I"0ËÙŒ¹˜¿·'_¶ŠôI½¦OKa0â<æ‹Z
ej-powøut0Õ¢AÈr'¦³lÅÝµž›Î rs§ë@ŒmË½À+0£ooÖc0÷ýãPë¶SÑÜéœÜôìæ»¬
öôö^TW¯Ó
F)AJ¢YžÕdŠlpU.
x‚—Ÿ4(¼¼ðò›çåµPž¥/ß%,!"õyyŒdéŸü9³»GO>ºôZøž­éyL|ˆJŒŒX
3E­lÍ–$¯ qÍaõµ'âË$‚e¾>öñóéŸ4Ÿ‰6FßÞžþm|ŠÝhð5¹þH÷{Ô¸Õ/‡»’¬+E¸¢µ\õ$ËÀ¡cÒšT‰Ê0M°ÒÐ3cÁg*


do you know why this data?

Comment: honestly I'm not sure what might be causing it. what do you get from a curl request on the command line, using no PHP code?